# Activity on users click in Bluetooth discoverability dialog

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-dialog

I am quite new to Java and would appreciate if someone could explain show me
how can I implement `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`  and
`onActivityResult()` in Bluetooth discoverability stated
[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#FindingDevices).

**What I want to achieve is**: on button `Enable BTDisco` click
**(**`if(bttn.getId() == R.id.bt_disco`**)** my program calls
`BTDiscoverable()` method:

```
public void BTDiscoverable() {
    Intent discoverableIntent = new
Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,
BT_ENABLE_TIME);
    startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
```

Now, the **[dialog](http://developer.android.com/images/bt_enable_request.png)** pops up. If user clicks no, the program should not
continue. If user click yes, `Enable BTDisco` button should become
unavailable and another button, lets call it `Start`, becomes available. I
wrote `onActivityResult` which would make `Start` button available but I
doubt it is done right. Snippet here:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent
data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            ((Button)            findViewById(R.id.bt_server_start)).setEnabled(true);
            BTCountDown = new BTTimer(BT_TIME_BTTIME,BT_TIME_BTTIME);
            BTCountDown.start();
        }
    }
}
```

`startActivityForResult` is called in `BTDiscoverable` method but it does
not provide what I wanted. I have followed **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result)** but as I am quite
new here, I have no idea how to implement this in such problem as mine.

The `onActivityResult` method is implemented class that `extends Activity`.
There are no errors while compiling. **Long story, short: `R.id.bt_server_start` stays disabled as initially programmed.**
Could really use some help.

Comment: So what is the problem you're facing? Everything seems to be fine.

Comment: The button `R.id.bt_server_start` stays disabled.

Comment: Did you make sure setEnabled gets called?

Comment: From `.xml`:  `<Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_server_start"         android:enabled="false"`. `setEnabled` is called in `onActivityResult` in the inner condition I guess?

Comment: What I meant is setEnabled(true)

Comment: if you put a break point in ((Button)            findViewById(R.id.bt_server_start)).setEnabled(true); then does it hit?

Comment: Craziest thing just happened. If I replace `if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)` with `if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)` and then I press cancel in the dialog, script works. WTF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put this

```
if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED)
```

Documentation says the following

Your activity will then receive a call to the onActivityResult()) callback, with the result code equal to the duration that the device is discoverable. If the user responded "No" or if an error occurred, the result code will be RESULT_CANCELED.

So if result code is not RESULT_CANCELED, then you are okay to enable your button.